# Problems with HOTP module in openam10

Tags: openam

I'm having problems trying to configure HOTP in openam10. I have configured Adaptive Risk Module and when the login attemp score is low the HOTP login form appears, everything is right by now, but when the use press the "Request OTP code" button nothing happens, no email is received, no error messages in openam logs, ...

Is there any known problem with this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried HOTP with OpenAM 10 but it works fine with 11. First take a look at the [documentation](https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/10.0.0/admin-guide#hotp-module-conf-hints) if you haven't done so already.

You can also set the OpenAM server in debug mode to collect more information by going to Configuration > Servers and Sites > SERVER_NAME > General > Debugging and setting the "Debug level" to "message" (A server restart might be required). Then, go through the login process one more time and take a look at the following debug files: Authentication and CoreSystem. You can search for this string: "HTOP:process()", which maps to the auth module entry point, and post the details here.

Hope this helps.